# Python Kusto SDK and Kusto UI returning different results

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm facing this very weird bug, where the Kusto Python SDK and Kusto Web UI are returning radically different results.

I'm running a query and am expecting to get a projection of fields, but for the same query, inside the same cluster, I get 2 radically different results.

When requesting to print the dataframe of the query result in Python, I get this:

```py
Name: Ratio_deviceCustomString5_s, dtype: Float64
0    0.0
Name: Ratio_deviceHostName_s, dtype: Float64
0    0.0
Name: Ratio_customerURI_s, dtype: Float64
0    0.0
Name: Ratio_bytesIn_s, dtype: Float64
0    0.0
Name: Ratio_bytesOut_s, dtype: Float64
0    0.0
```

Yet, when I'm running the query on the UI, I get the following results:
[image]

At first I thought that maybe I was shooting my queries at the wrong cluster but after ensuring that I passed the right cluster endpoint, and that the Kusto client's query endpoint was the right one.

The cluster I'm sending the requests to is a follower cluster, but I doubt the fact that it's a follower cluster affects the results by this much.

What could the issue be?

TIA!

Comment: try looking at them using `.show queries`, filter to these 2 specific (identical) queries, and look for differences - e.g. under `ScannedExtentsStatistics`, `ClientRequestProperties`, `WorkloadGroup`. then post your findings here. Also, check if the table has a row-level-security policy that may results with different output based on the identity of the caller.

Comment: You're right, it turns out there were RLS policies. Could it be possible for this to be more explicit (maybe thru some Exception or thrown Error?) It could help to do RCA.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a valid result of a user defined policy. You can submit a feature request for getting some indication in the response that RLS policies were applied (https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the code itself, but rather the RLS policies set upon the cluster.
Thanks @Yoni for the tip.